# What is the difference between creating a mesh from a single object to using multiple objects?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am learning Blender and I am watching tutorials and practicing from them. Recently I've followed two Blender users, Blender Guru and CG Masters, and I've noticed that while Andrew Price (Blender Guru) does his meshes from a single object, Aidy Burrows (CG Masters) does his work by shaping different objects and putting them together.

I was having a go at modeling a sword by myself for the first time and while I did finish it by following Andrew's method, I couldn't help but think throughout the process "how much easier would this be if I just do this in a 3 part mesh instead?". I tried doing some research before coming here and making a fool of myself by asking uninformed questions and from what I gather Andrew uses "Box Modeling" and Aidy uses "Edge Modeling".

I gather this information from [this webpage](https://www.lifewire.com/common-modeling-techniques-for-film-1953). I might be wrong, and feel free to correct me. In any case, I want to know what the repercussions of using each method are. Also, for which work is one more suited than the other? And the more information beyond that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.